# Working with Readonly List Property

Tags: vb.net

Gyzz I'm trying to create a user control with a Read-only List(Of Points) property. I'm having trouble in initializing and using that property! Help me , I'm pretty new to visual basic.

UserControl1:

```
Public Class PointEntryPanel

Dim P as List(of PointF) = New List(Of PointF)
Public ReadOnly Property Points as List(Of PointF)
    Get
        P = Points
        return P
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

Form:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDoubleClick


    ListBox1.Items.Add("You see ,No null reference exceptions")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("I want a property just like this")
    PointEntryPanel1.Points.Add(New PointF(0, 0))  'While this creates exceptions
    PointEntryPanel1.Points.Add(New PointF(1, 1))  'And the point is not added to the PList
    MessageBox.Show(PointEntryPanel1.PArray.ToString) 'this shows an empty box

End Sub

End Class
```

I want to code a property just like the ' Items ' Property in the List Box control

Comment: Is `PointEntryPanel1` in the second block supposed to be `UserControl1` and is `PArray` supposed to be using `Points`?  How does it not work with Magnus' answer?

Comment: Yup, thanks for notifying it , that was a mistake!!! I get a null reference exception and the points are not added by the " Points.Add " Method!

Comment: `Dim P as List(of PointF) = New List(Of Points)` wont compile.  if you fix that and just `return P` in the getter as in the answer it will work fine

Comment: Sorrrrry ! That too a mistake !

Comment: Still there's a null reference exception on Form1 : Line 8 , 9 !

Comment: That is something else (and not the complete message).  There is not 9 lines posted, so it would appear to be from something else somewhere other than what you have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate `P` and then return it in the property

```
Private p As New List(of PointF)
Public ReadOnly Property Points as List(Of PointF)
    Get
        return p
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: sorry about that , I forgot to insert the new keyword while writing this post! But i'm getting the null reference exeption at " P = Points" and nothing is added to PArray on "PointEntryPanel1.PArray.Add(New PointF(0, 0))"!! That's my problem

Comment: Skip `P = Points` and just return `P`

Comment: Still the 'PointEntryPanel1.PArray.Add(New PointF(0, 0))' does not do anything! I need that line to change 'P' list in the UserControl1 !!!!

Comment: I Want this PArray property like the 'Items' Property in the List Box Control

Comment: Sorry man that ain't " PArray " it Is " Points " !!! the code I'm using and the code I pasted here are different in naming!!!

Comment: @RagavSsr `Return p` is all you need in the getter.  Period.  try it

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the New List(of T).
Use "new" to do this.

For instance:

```
   Private Points As New List(Of Point) 'instantiate the List(of T)


Public ReadOnly Property AllPoints As List(Of Point)
    Get
        Return Points
    End Get
End Property
```

You can do something like this as well:

```
Public ReadOnly Property GetAllPoints As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return Points
    End Get
End Property 
'property only to return the List (for instance visible to
'users if you want to create a classlibrary.)



Private Property AllPoints As List(Of String)
    Set(value As List(Of String))
        If (Points.Equals(value)) Then Exit Property
        Points.Clear()
        Points.AddRange(value.ToArray)
    End Set
    Get
        Return Points
    End Get 'return the points
End Property
'Property to set and get the list (not visible in a classlibrary because it  
is private)
'this can be used in the class you have pasted it only.
```

Comment: I Want this PArray Property Like the 'Items' Property in the List Box control!! I can add separate method stubs to the user control for adding, removing and manipulating the items in P but it complicates my work!! It would be much easier this way , right!